# Postgres : Indexing switches to Parallel Seq Scan from index scan when queried for date range exceeding 2 days

Tags: postgresql

Database is running on Aurora Postgres db with 16vcpu,128GB RAM.

If the date range selected is more than 2 days, plan is getting switched to parallel seq scan instead of parallel index scan. Is there any reason why parallel seq scan is attached, if the wider date range is chosen.?  and how to force the query to use always parallel index scan.

enable_seqscan=off and vacuum the table. Both the option is not helping.

Query:

```
**SELECT
    s.exval_00,s.exval_01,  s.EXVAL_03,s.EXVAL_04,s.SAMPLE_DATE
FROM
    xxx.T_EXT_SAMPLES s
JOIN xxx.T_EXT_SAMPLES_CALC c ON
    c.SAMPLE_ID = s.SAMPLE_ID
WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND c.CH_ID IN (91111)
        AND c.SAMPLE_DATE = s.SAMPLE_DATE
    AND s.SAMPLE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2022-05-05 00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('2022-05-06 00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        AND s.EXVAL_07 IN ('T-EC-ER-TEOS')
    AND (s.EXVAL_09 IN ('xxxxxx1', 'xxxx-V01-PST.01') OR s.exval_15 IN ('xxxx-TEOS-V01-RUN.01', 'xxxx-V01-PST.01'));**
```

**Explain for 2 days(index scan)**: - Execution time:17sec

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..7080425.61 rows=1 width=1699) (actual time=5261.678..17069.465 rows=14 loops=1)
   I/O Timings: read=678843.320
   ->  Append  (cost=0.13..6953671.76 rows=180 width=1718) (actual time=900.938..17063.022 rows=312 loops=1)
         I/O Timings: read=678843.320
         Subplans Removed: 179
         ->  Index Scan using t_ext_samples_5_2022_sample_date_exval_00_exval_19_exval_01_idx on t_ext_samples_5_2022 s_1  (cost=0.57..6952228.43 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=900.937..17062.967 rows=312 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((sample_date >= to_date('2022-05-05 00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (sample_date <= to_date('2022-05-06 00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))
               Filter: (((exval_07)::text = 'T-EC-ER-TEOS'::text) AND (((exval_09)::text = ANY ('{xxxxx-V01-RUN.01,xxxxxTEOS-V01-PST.01}'::text[])) OR ((exval_15)::text = ANY ('{xxxxV01-RUN.01,xxxS-V01-PST.01}'::text[]))))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 3832755
               I/O Timings: read=678843.320
   ->  Append  (cost=0.15..702.39 rows=180 width=16) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=0 loops=312)
```

**Explain for >2 days(Parallel Seq scan)**: - Execution time:111sec

```
Gather  (cost=1000.72..11284108.20 rows=1 width=1690) (actual time=1364.885..111179.407 rows=30 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   I/O Timings: read=80156489.486
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..11283108.10 rows=1 width=1690) (actual time=2960.391..111120.888 rows=10 loops=3)
         I/O Timings: read=80156489.486
         ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.57..11156959.84 rows=180 width=1708) (actual time=1015.155..111113.961 rows=332 loops=3)
               I/O Timings: read=80156489.486
               Subplans Removed: 179
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on t_ext_samples_5_2022 s_1  (cost=0.00..11155518.78 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=1015.153..111113.904 rows=332 loops=3)
                     Filter: (((exval_07)::text = 'T-EC-ER-TEOS'::text) AND (sample_date >= to_date('2022-05-05 00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (sample_date <= to_date('2022-05-08 00:00'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)) AND (((exval_09)::text = ANY ('{xxxxxx-V01-RUN.01,xxxxxx-V01-PST.01}'::text[])) OR ((exval_15)::text = A
NY ('{xxxx-.01,xxxxV01-PST.01}'::text[]))))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 42149603
                     I/O Timings: read=80156489.486
         ->  Append  (cost=0.15..699.02 rows=180 width=16) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=996)
```

Comment: If setting `enable_seqscan = off` doesn't make the query execution faster, PostgreSQL made the correct choice with the sequential scan. It is slower because it has to chew more data. Your index is *very* ineffective; creating a better index could help a lot (but that was not your question).

Comment: Thx Laurenz for  the comment.  I want to create index as a last option as this table have got 6+ indexes

Comment: What do you mean that setting enable_seqscan=off didn't help?  It still did the seq scan anyway, or it didn't do the seq scan, but was still slow?

Comment: When i enable enable_seqscan=off ,  it is going for a Bitmap index scan and it is very slow compared to seq scan.